# Why isn't my output in base 8?

Tags: javascript, clock, radix

So I am looking to make a base8 clock. Still using twenty four 30<sub>8</sub> hours in a day, for convenience. I would have thought that converting the indivual values to base 8 in the last step before throwing them in an order and displaying them would work but I'm getting weird values out which are nowhere near the current time. It's even gave me numbers such as 9. Base8 has no 9, it has 11<sub>8</sub>.

Yes I based this on clock code I found on a site, I get lazy. Maybe this is my downfall. But can somebody tell me where I am going wrong?

```js
<!--

/*By JavaScript Kit
http://javascriptkit.com
Credit MUST stay intact for use
*/

function show2() {
  if (!document.all && !document.getElementById)
    return
  thelement = document.getElementById ? document.getElementById("tick2") : document.all.tick2
  var Digital = new Date();
  var hours = Digital.getHours();
  var minutes = Digital.getMinutes();
  var seconds = Digital.getSeconds();
  var hour8 = parseInt(hours, 8);
  var min8 = parseInt(minutes, 8);
  var sec8 = parseInt(seconds, 8);
  if (hour8 == 0)
    hour8 = 10
  var ctime = hour8 + ":" + min8 + ":" + sec8
  thelement.innerHTML = "<b style='font-size:14;color:blue;'>" + ctime + "</b>"
  setTimeout("show2()", 1000)
}
window.onload = show2
  //-->
```

```html
<span id=tick2>
</span>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apart from the fact that you need to do

```
setTimeout(show2, 1000)
```

without " and (), your use of parseInt is wrong, the radix is the base the string is ALREADY expressed in.

You need to do this

```
var hour8 = parseInt(hours).toString(8)
```

See [this jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jhhgx3r8/1/)

Comment: `parseInt(...)` is not needed, just `var hour8 = hours.toString(8);`

Answer (score 2):

You're using the parseInt function incorrectly. The second parameter is "An integer between 2 and 36 that represents the radix (the base in mathematical numeral systems) of the supplied string." Because your input is in decimal, but you're parameter says it's octal, the function fails to work as you expect.